# Is MySQL SSL really safe to use?

Tags: mysql, security, ssl

I was searching the web for an entire answer, but didn't really find any. My question: Is it safe to allow access to MySQL on my server directly from the internet, when I use the implemented SSL of MySQL?

My point is: MySQL SSL encrypts all communication and one can restrict the access to the database by forcing SSL (`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database> TO '<external_user>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass' REQUIRE SSL`), to allow access to the database only for users with a public key. All good.

However, I have to allow access to MySQL from any IP address (removing `bind-address 127.0.0.1`) and I have to open port 3306 in my firewall (in my case I use ufw as a front-end for iptables). These two steps seem very insecure for me (especially when i count the attempts to attack my port 22 in the fail2ban log).

Does anyone have a reason why I am wrong, an alternative idea or a set of settings to make this secure?

Note: I don't want to use an SSH Tunnel. It is certainly very secure, but to my knowledge reduces performance quite a lot.

Note II: I want to connect to the database with PHPs PDO class.

Comment: 'Save'? Do you mean '*safe*'? Are you asking whether SSL is safe? at this day and age?

Comment: @EJP No, I asked another question! A down vote? Honestly, read the question, before voting! And yes, I corrected the typo. And no, the title is correct, since many other articles on this topic, suggest using MySQL SSL instead of an SSH tunnel. Thus one might expect it to be equally safe. But according to the accepted answer it's not.

Comment: The title and the text both read 'save', until you corrected it, after my comment, which means they weren't correct at all. Your question is actually not about MySQL SSL at all, it is about the state of the port prior to the STARTTLS command, and the fact that it therefore allows plaintext connections.

Comment: Ok, I don't think this is the right forum to discuss simple typos, especially since it was completely clear what I ment. Next, your comment is at the moment rather useless. However, if you attempt to provide an alternative answer to my question, you're kindly invited to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL as used in your setup secures the transport against sniffing and modifications - nothing more and nothing less. Your setting of `require SSL` only requires the client to use SSL (contrary to your claim of *"allow access to the database only for users with a public key"*). It does not enforce the use of specific client certificates or even client certificates at all. This means anybody knowing the password can connect.

Thus, proper access control of your database still depends only on all passwords staying secret. And while SSL helps against sniffing the password from the connection and against modifying traffic (i.e. changing statements) it does not help against an attacker already knowing the password.

TLS does not help either to protect against problems at your client, like the attacker being able to inject his own SQL statements using SQL injection. And, exposing the database directly to the internet makes it vulnerable to denial of service attacks and also to brute-forcing passwords, no matter if SSL is used or not.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. I understood, my fears were reasonable. Can you suggest a way to achieve security, or will I just need to change my approach?

Comment: @PeMa: Unfortunately you don't show a narrow enough use case for why you need to have the database available from outside and with which restrictions. But if this is needed only for few specific clients a tunneling of the connection with SSH or VPN  reduces the exposed attack surface and thus the risk. A better site for asking such questions would actually be security.stackexchange.com. But make sure to specify your use case as narrow as possible to get more usable answers.

Comment: Ok, great I didn't know about security.stackexchange.com. The use case here is to create several web-apps for a company. For scalability reason of the apps, I thought about using xampp (or maybe php build-in server) locally on the mobile devices to communicate with one central data server.

Comment: @PeMa: If all these machines are inside the same internal network then you might restrict access to the database from only inside the internal network. Depending on the setup of the network this can be done by binding to the specific internal IP address or by adding appropriate firewall rules. If these machines are instead in several outside networks then a VPN might be useful.

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich:  They are not in the same network, but a VPN sounds good.  Ok, so I'll need to learn how to do this properly. Thanks for your kind and useful answers.